# Removing duplicates values with join

Tags: sql-server, duplication

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
B.Company,
COUNT(*) AS QTY
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B
ON A.CompanySk = B.EDWCompanySK
WHERE A.StartedDate >= '20171128'
GROUP BY B.Company
ORDER BY QTY DESC
```

However, there is a field name "Ticket" in table1 that has duplicate values, that I need to exclude. How can I return the count with excluding duplicate "ticket" values.

Comment: Can table1.Ticket be NULL?

Comment: There are zero NULL values in Table1.Ticket

Comment: Use `COUNT(DISTINCT Table1.Ticket)`

Answer (score 4):

Use the next query

```
SELECT
B.Company,
COUNT(DISTINCT A.Ticket) AS QTY
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B
ON A.CompanySk = B.EDWCompanySK
WHERE A.StartedDate >= '20171128'
GROUP BY B.Company
ORDER BY QTY DESC
```

Comment: It is returning the error: "The multi-part identifier Table1.Ticket could not be bound."

Comment: I've corrected my answer